# Solving power problem

Tags: power-series

Does anyone know why
$$\frac C{1+r}+\frac C{(1+r)^2}+\frac C{(1+r)^3}+\cdots=\frac Cr?$$

It probably has to do with power basics, but how to solve it.

Comment: What did you try so far? Take $c$ in front of the expression and you're left with a simple power series.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Geometric progression gives you :

$1+ \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} + ... = \frac{1}{1-x}$

Take $c$ in front of the expression and you're left with:
$$c \bigg(\frac{1}{1+r} + \frac{1}{(1+r)^2} + ... \bigg)$$

I think you can see the solution from here.

Answer (score 1):

$$\require{color}\frac{C}{1+r}+\frac{C}{(1+r)^2}+\frac{C}{(1+r)^3}+\cdots = {C\color{red}\left(\frac{1}{1+r}+\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+r)^3}+\cdots\right)}=\boxed{C\color{red}{x}}$$

Then,

$$(r+1)C{\color{red}x}=C\left(1+\underbrace{{\color{red}\frac1{r+1}+\frac1{(r+1)^2}+\cdots}}_{x}\right) $$

This is,

$$(r+1){\color{red}x} = 1+{\color{red}x}\implies {\color{red}x} = \frac1r$$

Hence,

$$\boxed{C{\color{red}x}} = \frac Cr$$

**EDIT:** solving equation $(r+1){\color{red}x} = 1+{\color{red}x}$.

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
(r+1){\color{red}x}& = 1+{\color{red}x}\\
r\cdot{\color{red}x}+1\cdot{\color{red}x}& = 1+{\color{red}x}\\
r\cdot{\color{red}x}+{\color{red}x}& = 1+{\color{red}x}\\
r\cdot{\color{red}x}+\cancel{{\color{red}x}}& = 1+\cancel{{\color{red}x}}\\
r\cdot{\color{red}x}& = 1\\
{\color{red}x}& = \frac1r\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, what is Cx?  what does it represent?   BTW  Is this a financial source that simplify this kind of formulas?

Comment: $C$ multiplied by $x$. $x$ is defined at the sum in the answer. This is a standard trick for summing an infinite geometric series

Comment: Also this answer is only valid for $r>0$ or $r<-2$.

Comment: OK, what happened in the 3rd and fourth step?

Comment: The third step is the same as the second one but with the $x$ substituted. Then, solving for $x$ we get the value of the infinite sum. In the forth step, your original infinite sum is equal to $Cx$, by the definition of $x$, and thus equal to $C$ times the value of $x$, this is, $1/r$.

Comment: I've edited for more clarity. Which is in red is *always* $x$. And what is in the boxes is what you aim to know.

Comment: It's all clear except for one step, solving 1+x = x(1+r) will lead to x=1+x/1+r, can you explain how would that equal 1/r?

Comment: I've included a step-by-step solution of the equation.

Comment: Thanks iqcd, it works now. It's a way better to understand how to solve things instead of memorizing. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Multiply the series by $1+r$ and subtract $C$. What do you get ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @daOnlyBG: this is clearly flagged as a hint. This is very common practice on Mathematics, isn't it ? The hint by Transcendental even says less.

Comment: yes, you are correct. Originally my impression was that short hints were supposed to be left in the comments, but this thread clarified it quite well: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10589/173397
I'll up vote your post

Comment: @daOnlyBG: thanks. I use to produce short/simple answers (hopefully not too short), as I believe there is value in brevity. I am "penalized" every now and then for this.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ 1+r = k $ so we want to show that $$\sum_{i=1}^{i=\infty}\frac{c}{k^{i}}=\frac{c}{r}$$
We sum of a geometric series which can be solved as, 
$$\frac{G}{1-R}$$, where G is the first term and R is the ratio.  So we get $$ \frac{c}{k(1-\frac{1}{k})}$$
$$ \frac{c}{(k-1)}$$
$$\frac{c}{r}$$